# Sonar 4.5.6 ignoring memory settings and getting out of memory

Tags: sonarqube

Since we've upgraded to Sonar 4.5.6 from 4.5.1 we're consistently getting out of memory errors on builds that have lots of tests. The build runs fine against the old 4.5.1 server but fails consistently against the 4.5.6 server.

We run Sonar through Maven 3.2.3 and JDK 7 using the `sonar:sonar` goal. I've tried setting either `MAVEN_OPTS` or `SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS` to `-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. I've also tried with `-Xmx2048m`. We continue to get out of memory issues.

```
04-Apr-2016 16:48:25    [ERROR] [16:48:25.872] Class not found: java.lang.annotation.Repeatable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:25    [ERROR] [16:48:25.961] Class not found: java.lang.annotation.Repeatable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:26    [ERROR] [16:48:26.541] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:26    [ERROR] [16:48:26.701] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:26    [ERROR] [16:48:26.701] Class not found: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
04-Apr-2016 16:48:26    [ERROR] [16:48:26.838] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:26    [ERROR] [16:48:26.960] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:27    [ERROR] [16:48:27.070] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:28    [ERROR] [16:48:28.055] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.671] Java Test Files AST scan done: 6423 ms
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.671] 139/139 source files have been analyzed
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.673] Package design analysis...
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.947] Package design analysis done: 274 ms
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.972] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 15533 ms
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.975] Sensor QProfileSensor...
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.976] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 1 ms
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.976] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor@44b9148f...
04-Apr-2016 16:48:29    [INFO] [16:48:29.980] Execute Findbugs 3.0.1...
04-Apr-2016 16:48:30    [INFO] [16:48:30.603] Found findbugs plugin: /<path to project>/target/sonar/findbugs/fb-contrib.jar
04-Apr-2016 16:48:30    [INFO] [16:48:30.603] Findbugs output report: /<path to project>/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
04-Apr-2016 16:49:54    [WARN] [16:49:54.965] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,471ms last 8 cycles average is 360ms
04-Apr-2016 16:50:39    The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
04-Apr-2016 16:50:40      org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
04-Apr-2016 16:50:42    Out of memory
04-Apr-2016 16:50:45    Total memory: 3650M
04-Apr-2016 16:50:46    free memory: 3510M
```

I'm really not sure how to proceed at this point. The total memory vs free memory indicates only 140MB is in use before it craps out, what memory settings is the sonar runner using? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share full logs with command invoked ? (also add the `-e` switch)

Comment: Looks like this was caused by running the sonar runner on JDK 7u71. When I ran on JDK 8 it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue had to do with running the sonar runner on `JDK 7u71`. When I switched to using `JDK 8` it didn't run out of memory. Looking at the [Sonar Requirements documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements), it seems you need `JDK 7u75` or higher, so maybe that's why?

Comment: I have a similar problem, do you have another solution?